# Compiling output to a file using DSH

Tags: c, output, system, nodes, monitoring

I've written a small C program (more like a script really) that gathers some general system information from a machine and prints it out (cpu, ram, system temperature, etc). I'm trying to gather this information for a large group of machines, so I'm using dsh to do so. This all works fine, and running the program through dsh prints the desired output to the screen.

However, I want to compile this output from all the machines using dsh into a single file. I thought that simply using 'program >> output' as my command for dsh would work, but since dsh runs in parallel the output just gets garbled up.

Is there a way to run dsh so that the nodes don't run in parralel, but wait for total completion before moving on? Or, is there a better way to output this information to a file entirely?

Comment: You could use PDSH instead of dsh: https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/wiki/UsingPDSH

Comment: @REACHUS Unfortunately I don't have sufficient privileges on the machine/server in question to install PDSH.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just writing to a file named the hostname.info for each machine I scanned, and then combined them all using cat with a bash script. Not elegant but it works.